# Cakephp dropdown list (selectlist) + how to display a value from the model and a related model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, dropdown, display

I would like to display in a dropdownlist (selectlist) that concatenated the value of a field form the model and and a field from a related model. I have a table 'working_day' which is linked to a table 'user' and 'pause'. In the view 'Pause'(add and edit), I have a dropdownlist that displays the working_day_id but I wish to displays the fields 'date' of 'WorkingDay' and the fields 'username' of 'User'.
For example : 13/04/2016 (jerome S).
I already tried $virtualfield, it work when i use field from 'WorkingDay' but it does not work when i use the field from 'User'.

[db schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORsbs.png)

the $virtualfield that i tried :

```
public $virtualFields = array('workingday_display_field' => 'concat(WorkingDay.date_working_day, " (", User.username, ")")');
public $displayField = 'workingday_display_field';
```

I also tried the solution proposed below but it does not work, the same problem occurs :

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['workingday_display_field'] = sprintf('concat(%s.date_working_day, " (", %s.username, ")")', $this->alias, $this->User->alias);    
    $this->displayField = "workingday_display_field";
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with doing it this way when using a different Model alias, another recommended way is to handle these in the Models construct method:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['name'] = sprintf('CONCAT(%s.first_name, " ",%s.last_name)', $this->alias, $this->alias);
    $this->virtualFields['namewithemail'] = sprintf('CONCAT(%s.first_name, " ", %s.last_name, " (", %s.email, ")")', $this->alias, $this->alias, $this->alias);
    $this->displayField = "namewithemail";
}
```

This is described in this section of the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation where I need to create a list that combines two fields from different tables. What I ended up doing was overriding find() to return the appropriate list.

```
public function find($type = 'first', $params = array()) {
    $workingdays = array();

    if ($type == 'list'){
        $params = array_merge(
            array('contain' => array('User')),
            $params
        );
        $workingdaysUnformatted = parent::find('all', $params);
        foreach($workingdaysUnformatted as $workingday){
            $workingdays['WorkingDay']['workingday_display_field'] = $workingday['WorkingDay']['date'].' ('.$workingday['User']['username'].')'
        }
    }
    else
        $workingdays = parent::find($type, $params);

    return $workingdays;
}
```

There may be a classier way to format the list that you want to return, but this illustrates the general idea.